# How to render WP Rest-API Endpoints in a React.js Theme with Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, templates, rest-api, backbone

I am building a Ecommerce Wordpress/Woocommerce Theme using React.js.  I am using the npm package:

[create-react-wptheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-wptheme)

This package renders the react app directly inside of the index.php of the wordpress theme.

I am unsure how to access the wordpress api endpoints inside of react.js components.  I have created the templates for the site using jsx, and need to access the api Endpoints to render dynamic content.  I can access the points using http requests to the external api, but I need to be able to access the full api inside of the react-wp-theme.

From what I understand I need to use the backbone.js api client to access the wp rest-api using react.

Or do i possibly need a npm package to hook this up.

How can I make the api available inside of my app.js and components?

I want to make a basic GET request to fetch the posts object, but I do not know how to import the wp Rest-API into react.

Here is a post page where I am trying to fetch a post.  It brings up an error.
Here is the page:

```
    import React from "react";


    class Post extends React.Component {
      render() {
        let wpPosts = new window.wp.api.collections.Posts();
wpPosts.fetch({ data: { per_page: 2 } }).done(posts => {
          posts.forEach(post => {
            console.log(post.title.rendered);
        });
        return (
          <div className="container indigo lighten-4">
            <div className="container flow-text py-5 mt-5">
              <h1>Title</h1>
              <p>
                content
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Post;
```

This Page Does not display here is the error from the console.

```
    Post.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined
    at Post.render (Post.js:6)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15141)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15096)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15980)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19102)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19143)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18350)
render @ Post.js:6
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:15141
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:15096
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:15980
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:19102
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:19143
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:196
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:250
replayUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:18350
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19261
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:20165
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:20075
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:20049
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:19904
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:19711
scheduleRootUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:20415
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:20441
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:20509
push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render @ react-dom.development.js:20820
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:20974
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:20292
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:20970
render @ react-dom.development.js:21037
./src/index.js @ index.js:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ serviceWorker.js:135
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
react-dom.development.js:16764 The above error occurred in the <Post> component:
    in Post (created by Route)
    in Route (at Routes.js:29)
    in Switch (at Routes.js:20)
    in Routes (at App.js:18)
    in div (at App.js:16)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:15)
    in App (at src/index.js:6)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://fb.me/react-error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:16764
logError @ react-dom.development.js:16800
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:17814
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:11743
commitUpdateEffects @ react-dom.development.js:11783
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11773
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:17055
commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:18512
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:196
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:250
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:18717
completeRoot @ react-dom.development.js:20247
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:20170
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:20075
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:20049
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:19904
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:19711
scheduleRootUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:20415
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:20441
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:20509
push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render @ react-dom.development.js:20820
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:20974
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:20292
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:20970
render @ react-dom.development.js:21037
./src/index.js @ index.js:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ serviceWorker.js:135
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
react-dom.development.js:20135 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined
    at Post.render (Post.js:6)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15141)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15096)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15980)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19102)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19143)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19228)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20165)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20075)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20049)
```

Here is my functions.php that I created to access the api.

```
<?php

function my_theme_scripts() {
  // Enqueue the Backbone JavaScript Client.
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );

?>
```

Here is My index.php

```
<?php
  $TEMPLATE_PATH = parse_url(get_template_directory_uri(), PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
        <!-- Material Icons -->
        <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="<?php echo $TEMPLATE_PATH; ?>/manifest.json">
    <?php wp_head(); ?> 

    <title>React WordPress Theme</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    </body>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</html>
```

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./scss/App.scss";
import "./scss/pbml.scss";
import Headers from "./routers/Headers";
import Footer from "./components/footer/Footer";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";

import Routes from "./routers/Routes";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="cosmos">
          <Headers />
          <Routes />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And Here is my index.js that just points the root to my app.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/) might help.

Comment: I have read the documentation, but I am having difficulty importing the rest-api into my react components.  I updated the question to include more info.

Comment: You enqueue scripts on the front-end using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook - e.g. In `functions.php`, do `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){ wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' ); } )`.

Comment: But, you don't have `wp_head();` in your template (`index.php`), so you could put it there - before `</head>`, or try adding `wp_print_scripts( 'wp-api' );` before `</body>`..

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have expanded the project to include a functions.php, and added the wp_head and wp_footer to my index.php.  I still have the same error, because Im not sure how to access the wp-api in react.  What do I call in the js file to import wp?

Comment: Try using `window.wp` instead of just `wp` - `new window.wp.api.collections.Posts`, like [this](https://pastebin.com/RSh4jtez). You can also check my [`index.php`](https://pastebin.com/v3Fg60ww) and [`functions.php`](https://pastebin.com/zj3t78yN) files (just ignore the HTML comments which were auto-generated by the NPM package..) - my theme is `wp-content/themes/my_react_theme`. Btw, you got a typo there - `console.log(wpPost)` - it's `wpPosts` (with 's') and not `wpPost`.

Comment: Thank you Sally,  I have updated my question with edits I made that you advised.  I am getting a new error, and still can not import the api.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: I have not resolved this issue yet.  My internet broke for a few days.  From what I can tell I have my app wired up similarly to your examples, but I am still unable to access the wp endpoints.  I am unsure what the issue is.  Any help would be greatly appreciates. :)

Comment: Check my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can access the points using http requests to the external api, but I
>   need to be able to access the full api inside of the react-wp-theme.

You could use either the [`wp-api` script / Backbone JavaScript client library](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/) or one of the other client libraries [listed here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/client-libraries/) such as the [`node-wpapi` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi).

### Using the `wp-api` script

1. Enqueue the script:

   ```
   wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );
   ```
2. In `index.php`, make sure `<?php wp_head(); ?>` is added in the document `head`, and `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in the `body`.

And then in your React *components*, access the client via `window.wp.api` instead of just `wp.api`:

```
const postsCollection = new window.wp.api.collections.Posts(); // like this
//const postsCollection = new wp.api.collections.Posts();      // not this
```

Here's an example React Component which uses the `Posts` collection to retrieve one post: (the markup is based on your `Post` component)

```
import React from "react";

class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      item: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Instantiates the collection.
    const postsCollection = new window.wp.api.collections.Posts();

    // Retrieves one post.
    postsCollection.fetch({ data: { per_page: 1 } })
      .done(posts => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          item: posts[0]
        });
      })
      .error((xhr, status, error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, item } = this.state;
    if (error || item.errors) {
      return <div>Error: {error || 'API error...'}</div>;
    } else if (! isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="container indigo lighten-4">
          <div className="container flow-text py-5 mt-5">
            <h3>{item.title.rendered}</h3>
            <p>{item.excerpt.rendered}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Tried and tested working, and the code is based on [the official example](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#example-using-ajax-results-to-set-local-state).

### Using the `node-wpapi` library

You can refer to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi) on [installing the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi#installation) and [using it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi#using-the-client).

But here's the above `Post` component, adapted to using the `node-wpapi` library: (the `...` means nothing changed)

```
import React from "react";

const WPAPI = require('wpapi');
const wp = new WPAPI({
  endpoint: 'http://example.com/wp-json'
});

class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Retrieves one post.
    wp.posts().perPage(1)
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          item: posts[0]
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error: err.message
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default Post;
```

### The Full Code

You can check my files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r1my4p8sng7kaw9/AABjR-i8ZdzdJPZ9qIlvNuRaa?dl=0).

Comment: Thank you Sally.  It seems that enqueing the script in the index let me access the backbone api.  It works now.  :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you got it working. :) I did suspect the `wp-api` script was not enqueued (since you had already attempted `window.wp.api`), but in my case, enqueuing the script via `functions.php` also did work. :)